# Retrieving data in recycler view not working -query correction

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a problem retrieving data from Firebase. I am attaching the structure of my database in the figure.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4Bfr.png)
Here I have the parent node as "Reply", inside that I have replykey, inside push key parent for each node have its children. I like to fetch data based on particular "teacherID" that matches the current teacher. The query I wrote is shown below

```
RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); 
  query=RootRef.child("Reply").orderByChild("teacherID").equalTo(CurrentTeacherrId);
       FirebaseRecyclerOptions<StudentModelClass> options =
               new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<StudentModelClass>()
                       .setQuery(InstRef,StudentModelClass.class)
                       .build();
```

Using this code recycleView is not fetching the data. How I can rewrite the query to fetch data correctly

Comment: Where in the database do you have such a node `FirstReply`?

Comment: @AlexMamo  sorry I corrected .. it is Reply .. that was a typing mistake.. question is correct

Comment: Are you storing the "reply key" somewhere in your code?

Comment: @AlexMamo, no I am not saving reply key..

Comment: In that case, you should, so you can use it in your reference, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo, That are random keys , whether with out saving that random keys whether I can do with help of for loop ?

Comment: You say your recycler view is not displaying any data try running the reference alone using snapshot listener and check it it returns the data or not. If yes, then you need attach the `startListening();` to your adapter to start getting data.

Comment: Also, check if your recycler model class contains the same name for field values as in database if not use the `@PropertyName("")` over each item and getter and setter. `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` works only when the field names match.

Comment: @VenkateshTalacheeru, startListening() is not the problem , I have used that. please check my database there are reply key and push key after parent node., so a normal query will not do the task ,

Comment: What is the purpose of the push key ?

Comment: @Zain ..Push keys are used to retain the individuality of each node , it is necessary